# getting the positions of the occurrences of one item in a sequence

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

From a a sequence, I need to fetch all the positions of the occurrence of a given item.

I'm asking myself if this is a good way to solve the problem:

```
(defn get-positions [item coll]
  (->> (map-indexed vector coll)
       (filter (fn [[_ v]] (= item v)))
       (map first)))
```

This also works for strings, they'll be transformed to a sequence by the first map. However, if I know the input's are strings, would there be a more string specific approach for this problem?

Comment: This is exactly how I would solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a general solution to the problem, why would you want to spend more effort to try to come up with a more specific one? The benefits of doing so here are negligible.

Just for variety's sake, here's another way to implement your function:

```
(defn positions [x coll]
  (keep-indexed #(when (= x %2) %1) coll))
```

Comment: alright, I see. I was looking for an "filter-indexed", and keep-indexed is very similar. only the nil/false thing differs. I'd just switch [coll x] to [x coll], since I found out that having the coll in the end is often useful.

Comment: @AntonHarald Fair enough; I switched the parameter order in my answer.