# pass only nth argument

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Is there a built-in way to pass only the n-th argument to another function. consider this:

```
(defn nth-arg [i & args]
  (nth args i))
```

and for convenience:

```
(def arg1 (partial nth-arg 0))
(def arg2 (partial nth-arg 1))
(def arg3 (partial nth-arg 2))
```

This would make possible to avoid constructs like (fn [_ _ x] (foo x)) :

```
(comp foo arg3)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of an actual function in which this would be useful?

Comment: actually I bumped into this through the code in the post, that you just answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470950/getting-the-positions-of-the-occurrences-of-one-item-in-a-sequence/35471392?noredirect=1#comment58638472_35471392

Comment: In the anonymous function that you pass to `filter`, you're actually destructuring a vector, *not* taking the second argument. You could rewrite it as `(comp (partial = item) second)`.

Comment: true! That's right..  I'll think about another example..

Comment: Why do you have a problem using (fn [_ _ x] (foo x))? I don't know how it would be useful. I'd say you basically answered yourself. It's unlikely that anyone will write an arity 3 function that uses only with the third argument. If you pass the 3rd argument only, you're likely to get a null pointer exception because the other 2 arguments are there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is good style to only accept arguments that will be used in your functions. In cases where you may think it convenient to accept more, consider transforming the inputs instead. Keeping a distinction between a function application and a data selection is a good thing.

Sometimes you are forced to create functions that don't use the first argument, for example when defining protocols, often you don't need the `this` argument, so you just discard it. Here it is again better to be explicit and direct about what is happening. You wont make the code any more elegant by delegating to another function, just another mental step to follow for the reader.

Avoid vardic behavior when it doesn't benefit you. You are sacrificing a real benefit (arity checking). It opens you up to hard to reason about errors (opps I should have applied that vector instead of passing it! Dang I had 4 parameters instead of 3 after I refactored to not need the 2nd argument).